# Understanding Node / promise in reading a csv to an array (getting values out of the promise)

Tags: node.js, csv, promise, es6-promise

I want to read a .csv file into an array, get the number of rows read, and send the array off to another function for additional processing.

I searched and found some sample code that works (except being able to get values out of the promise).

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')

async function readCsv(csv_file_path) {

    const list = []     // read .csv into array (list)
    var num_rows = 0    // the number of rows read

    fs.createReadStream(csv_file)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => list.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
            num_rows = list.length
            console.log('num_rows', num_rows) // prints num rows read, fine
        })

    // now, here, at this point in the code, I want to use:
    //  1. num_rows
    //  2. address_list outside fo the fs.createReadStream function
    // how do I do this?

    // Here, outside, num_rows is 0, and nothing is in the list
    console.log('num_rows:', num_rows)
    for (let address of address_list) {
        console.log('address:', address);
    }

    // how do I get the value for num_rows, and contents of list[] set,
    // so I can use here at this point in the code?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a library for `.csv` parsing. A good one is [`csv-parse`](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-parse), you can install it using `npm`.

Here's a simple example using the synchronous API.

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync')

const input = `
"key_1","key_2"
"value 1","value 2"
"value 3","value 3"
`
const records = parse(input, {
  skip_empty_lines: true
})

console.log(records)

// Output:
// [ [ 'key_1', 'key_2' ],
// [ 'value 1', 'value 2' ],
// [ 'value 3', 'value 3' ] ]
// Just get the length of the output array to get the number of rows in the file
```

You can find the API documentation **[here](https://csv.js.org/parse/api/)**.

Comment: Parsing the .csv is not the problem, as you see in the code I posted, I am doing this successfully.  I am not having issues in parsing the .csv.

You have been mistaken, this is not a post dealing with issues in parsing a .csv, please read the problem again.

For future reference, please refrain from drive by responses that do not help get closer to the solution.

It pollutes the issue/posting which wastes times of those searching and may find this, having the same problem in the future.

Please delete your answer.